# How do I use an array as an object attribute in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, constructor

I need some help regarding the arrays in Perl

This is the constructor I have.

BuildPacket.pm

```
     sub new {
            my $class = shift;    
            my $Packet = {
                _PacketName => shift,
                _Platform  => shift,
                _Version => shift,
                _IncludePath => [@_],
            };

            bless $Packet, $class;
            return $Packet;
        }

        sub SetPacketName {
            my ( $Packet, $PacketName ) = @_;
            $Packet->{_PacketName} = $PacketName if defined($PacketName);
            return $Packet->{_PacketName};
        }

       sub SetIncludePath {
            my ( $Packet, @IncludePath ) = @_;
            $Packet->{_IncludePath} = \@IncludePath;
        }

         sub GetPacketName {
            my( $Packet ) = @_;
            return $Packet->{_PacketName};
        }

        sub GetIncludePath {
           my( $Packet ) = @_;
           @{ $Packet->{_IncludePath} };
        }
```

(The code has been modified according to the suggestions from 'gbacon', thank you)

I am pushing the relative paths into 'includeobjects' array in a dynamic way. The includepaths are being read from an xml file and are pushed into this array.

```
# PacketInput.pm
if($element eq 'Include')
            {
             while( my( $key, $value ) = each( %attrs ))
                {
                if($key eq 'Path')
                    push(@includeobjects, $value);
                        }
                }
```

So, the includeobject will be this way:

```
@includeobjects = (
    "./input/myMockPacketName",
    "./input/myPacket/my3/*.txt",
    "./input/myPacket/in.html",
);
```

I am using this line for set include path

```
 $newPacket->SetIncludePath(@includeobjects);
```

Also in `PacketInput.pm`, I have

```
sub CreateStringPath
{
    my $packet = shift;
    print "printing packet in CreateStringPath".$packet."\n";
    my $append = "";
    my @arr = @{$packet->GetIncludePath()};
    foreach my $inc (@arr)
    {
        $append = $append + $inc;
        print "print append :".$append."\n";
    }
}
```

I have many packets, so I am looping through each packet

```
# PacketCreation.pl
my @packets = PacketInput::GetPackets();
foreach my $packet (PacketInput::GetPackets())
{
    print "printing packet in loop packet".$packet."\n";
    PacketInput::CreateStringPath($packet);
    $packet->CreateTar($platform, $input);
    $packet->GetValidateOutputFile($platform);
}
```

The get and set methods work fine for PacketName. But since IncludePath is an array, I could not get it to work, I mean the relative paths are not being printed.

Comment: Ow my eyes. Why are you not using `use strict; use warnings;`?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out!! Now i am using them. :)

Comment: The assignment to `@includeobjects` has a syntax error that won't allow your program to run at all (which you can fix by changing it to `@includeobjects = qw[ ./input/myMockPacketName ./input/myPacket/my3/*.txt ./input/myPacket/in.html ];`). Please copy-and-paste so we can help you fix your code instead of guessing what it might be.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I modified the code similar to what i have with regards to the includeobjects array which is dynamically pushed with the relative paths. i want to append the paths in method CreateStringPath

Comment: The code you added also contained a syntax error: missing braces around `push(@includeobjects, $value)`. It's important that you copy-and-paste your code rather than retyping it. I modified my answer to use the same `@includeobjects` as yours, and the output looks fine. You've told us the output you didn't get, so what did you get? That's also important information!

Comment: is there anyway i can show you all the code i have, so that you can suggest me where i am at fault. I really appreciate your effort in trying to help me. This project is very important for me as a newbie

Comment: I think I see the problem. Does `PacketInput.pm` have the `strict` pragma enabled? `GetIncludePath` returns an array, but `CreateStringPath` has `@{$packet->GetIncludePath()}`, which treats it as a *reference* to an array. I'll modify my answer to make `GetIncludePath` a little smarter about its return value with `wantarray`.

Comment: I have enabled strict. I want to show you all the code i have from 2 modules and 1 pl file. How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried my updated `GetIncludePath` yet? I believe it will fix your problem, but it not, you could dump all your code into http://pastebin.com/ and give a link to it in a comment. Be sure to enable `use warnings` and `use strict` on all three of your source files! Those safety guards will make your life much easier.

Comment: print reference in set include path :ARRAY(0x1a8dbf4)
printing packet in packetcreation.pl BuildPacket=HASH(0x1abe3f4)
printing packet in CreateStringPath BuildPacket=HASH(0x1abe3f4)
reference in getinclude path :ARRAY(0x1a9738c)

When you see the array reference in set includepath and get includepath, they are not the same, that may be the problem i am not getting any values in the array of @path, which you have suggested

Comment: Your implementation of `BuildPacket` is up to the job. The include paths aren't making it into the objects because of how you're processing the XML input.

Comment: There's a patch at the end of your pastebin post that fixes the problems with respect to processing of the include paths. If that prompts other questions, feel free to create new questions here on Stack Overflow. (It wouldn't be appropriate to continue discussing in *this* question issues not related to using arrays as object attributes.)

Comment: I am sorry, but where can i find the patch at the end of my pastebin post. I dont see anything

Comment: i think you need to post me a new link which you get after making the modifications.

Comment: @superstar I haven't forgotten about you: the code is on another machine. I have no idea how the updated paste got lost. :-(

Comment: @gbacon i think you need to post me a new link which you will be getting after making the modifications. ( I guess your modified new code will not be showed at the bottom of my old post). thank very much for being patient and your desire to help me...thanks!!

Comment: @superstar See http://pastebin.com/Tu8xejkc

Comment: @gbacon Thank you very much for your time and patience. I really appreciate that. Thanks once again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you enable the strict pragma, the code doesn't even compile:

```
Global symbol "@_IncludePath" requires explicit package name at Packet.pm line 15.
Global symbol "@_IncludePath" requires explicit package name at Packet.pm line 29.
Global symbol "@_IncludePath" requires explicit package name at Packet.pm line 30.
Global symbol "@_IncludePath" requires explicit package name at Packet.pm line 40.
```

Don't use `@` unquoted in your keys because it will confuse the parser. I recommend removing them entirely to avoid confusing human readers of your code.

You seem to want to pull all the attribute values from the arguments to the constructor, so continue peeling off the scalar values with [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html), and then everything left must be the include path.

I assume that the components of the include path will be simple scalars and not references; if the latter is the case, then you'll want to make deep copies for safety.

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;

  my $Packet = {
    _PacketName  => shift,
    _Platform    => shift,
    _Version     => shift,
    _IncludePath => [ @_ ],
  };

  bless $Packet, $class;
}
```

Note that there's no need to store the blessed object in a temporary variable and then immediately return it because of the [semantics of Perl subs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION):

> If no `return` is found and if the last statement is an expression, its value is returned.

The methods below will also make use of this feature.

Given the constructor above, `GetIncludePath` becomes

```
sub GetIncludePath {
  my( $Packet ) = @_;
  my @path = @{ $Packet->{_IncludePath} };
  wantarray ? @path : \@path;
}
```

There are a couple of things going on here. First, note that we're careful to return a copy of the include path rather than a direct reference to the internal array. This way, the user can modify the value returned from `GetIncludePath` without having to worry about mucking up the packet's state.

The [`wantarray` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) allows a sub to determine the context of its call and respond accordingly. In list context, `GetIncludePath` will return the list of values in the array. Otherwise, it returns a reference to a copy of the array. This way, client code can call it either as in

```
foreach my $path (@{ $packet->GetIncludePath }) { ... }
```

or

```
foreach my $path ($packet->GetIncludePath) { ... }
```

`SetIncludePath` is then

```
sub SetIncludePath {
  my ( $Packet, @IncludePath ) = @_;
  $Packet->{_IncludePath} = \@IncludePath;
}
```

Note that you could have used similar code in the constructor rather than removing one parameter at a time with `shift`.

You might use the class defined above as in

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Packet;

sub print_packet {
  my($p) = @_;
  print $p->GetPacketName, "\n",
        map("  - [$_]\n", $p->GetIncludePath),
        "\n";
}

my $p = Packet->new("MyName", "platform", "v1.0", qw/ foo bar baz /);
print_packet $p;

my @includeobjects = (
    "./input/myMockPacketName",
    "./input/myPacket/my3/*.txt",
    "./input/myPacket/in.html",
);
$p->SetIncludePath(@includeobjects);
print_packet $p;

print "In scalar context:\n";
foreach my $path (@{ $p->GetIncludePath }) {
  print $path, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
MyName
  - [foo]
  - [bar]
  - [baz]

MyName
  - [./input/myMockPacketName]
  - [./input/myPacket/my3/*.txt]
  - [./input/myPacket/in.html]

In scalar context:
./input/myMockPacketName
./input/myPacket/my3/*.txt
./input/myPacket/in.html
```

Comment: I tried to implement the changes, and tried to print the array @{ $Packet->{_IncludePath} } from GetIncludePath, and it shows up nothing

Comment: @superstar The array will be empty initially because `my @includeobjects = ()` in the constructor creates a new, empty array. Code such as `$packet->SetIncludePath(qw/ foo bar baz /)` will give it an interesting value. Did you do this in your test?

Comment: I am actually using $newPacket->SetIncludePath(@includeobjects); in another module to pass the array of includeobjects, I should get these array values in GetIncludePath, which is not happening..

Comment: @brian d foy: when i call a $packet->GetIncludePath, i should be able to get the array values which has been set from SetIncludePath...right?

Comment: @superstar Take a look at the working example in the updated answer that stores and retrieves the include path. How is your code different?

Comment: @gbacon: thanks, that was in similar lines and your code works fine. But i have @other array to be ./input/myMockPacketName ./input/myPacket/my3/*.txt ./input/myPacket/in.html which are relative paths. so my include paths are specific and when i run with this as array, it doesnot work.

Comment: @superstar By doesn't work, do you mean it's not expanding the wildcard in the second path or something else? Please edit your question to show how you're using the class and the output you'd like to see so we can give you more helpful answers.

Comment: I enabled according to what you have specified. But the length of arr in CreateStringPath shows up as zero.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to reduce typing is to use Moose.

```
package Packet;
use Moose::Policy 'Moose::Policy::JavaAccessors';
use Moose;

has 'PacketName' => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'Str',
    required => 1,
);

has 'Platform' => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'Str',
    required => 1,
);

has 'Version' => (
    is       => 'rw',
    isa      => 'Int',
    required => 1,
);

has 'IncludePath' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
    default  => sub {[]},
    traits => [ 'Array' ],
    handles => {
        getIncludePath       => 'elements',
        getIncludePathMember => 'get',
        setIncludePathMember => 'set',
    },
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
no Moose;
1;
```

Check out [Moose::Manual::Unsweetened](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Unsweetened.pod) for another example of how Moose saves time.

If you are adamant in your desire to learn classical Perl OOP, read the following [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/) articles: [perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html), [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html), [perlfreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

A great book about classical Perl OO is [Damian Conway's Object Oriented Perl](http://www.manning.com/conway/).  It will give you a sense of the possibilities in Perl's object.

Comment: Class::Accessor is a reasonable alternative if Moos eis absolutely out of the question. But Moose rocks.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation and for the book suggested

Comment: Nothing against Moose, but I wouldn't say that one of its benefits is typing reduction. I think it's much too verbose and look forward to the day when it can generate the Moose code from a text description of the class.

Comment: @brian, that is an interesting idea.  IME, Moose can be verbose, but it much more compact than writing out classical Perl OOP classes.  Big savings come from types, coercion, method generation.  But I would welcome a less verbose, punctuated syntax for object declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Once you understand [@gbacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561451/how-do-i-use-an-array-as-an-object-attribute-in-perl/2561515#2561515), you can save some typing by using [Class::Accessor::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Class::Accessor::Fast):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package My::Class;
use strict; use warnings;
use base 'Class::Accessor::Fast';

__PACKAGE__->follow_best_practice;
__PACKAGE__->mk_accessors( qw(
    IncludePath
    PacketName
    Platform
    Version
));

use overload '""' => 'to_string';

sub to_string {
    my $self = shift;
    sprintf(
        "%s [ %s:%s ]: %s",
        $self->get_PacketName,
        $self->get_Platform,
        $self->get_Version,
        join(':', @{ $self->get_IncludePath })
    );
}

my $obj = My::Class->new({
        PacketName => 'dummy', Platform => 'Linux'
});
$obj->set_IncludePath([ qw( /home/include /opt/include )]);
$obj->set_Version( '1.05b' );
print "$obj\n";
```